# scroll inertia with non-Apple devices

Tags: mouse, macos

So I use Logitech and Wacom mice and tablets.

Is there a way to enable scroll momentum/inertia with non-Apple devices across all macOS?

Or at least Chrome...

Comment: This is a great question. I would like this functionality myself. One interesting thing is FF doesn't do inertia even with a touch pad, so I'm guessing they messed with the scrolling settings there. I'm curious why you need this functionality or if you would just prefer it?

Comment: We live in a scrolling world. We scroll maybe hundreds of times every day... With inertia you actually have to scroll less. When using a mouse, not having inertia can be uncomfortable... but when using a graphic tablet not having inertia is a real pain.

Answer (score -1):

Mos app for macOS is a good solution for all non-apple mice to behave like apple's ones. Check it out.

Comment: What is "Mos app", where can people find it?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/342318)

Comment: 'Mos macos' Google search string, first link.

Comment: Please **edit** the question with helpful details, including the actual link. Answers which just send people to google details themselves tend to be attract downvotes.